# Ассемблер, найти частоту встречаемости элемента

Tags: массивы, ассемблер, матрицы

Помогите написать программу. Как не пытаюсь не выходит. Нужно в матрице 3 на 4, ну вообще то не важно, но возьмем 3 на 4, найти частоту встречаемости элементов. Каждый элемент, который берем записывать в массив а, а потом в этом массиве тоже проверять на встречаемость, чтобы ее не было. В матрице сравнивать элементы, и если они равны, то записывать в массив b и увеличивать, если встречается еще раз. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как переходить на массивы a и b , как осуществлять проверку там...

Comment: "*Каждый элемент, который берем записывать в массив а, а потом в этом массиве тоже проверять на встречаемость, чтобы ее не было*" - вот это мне совершенно не понятно. Ну, допустим, каждый элемент  `m[3][4]` мы запишем в массив `a[12]`. Зачем там-то проверять, если элементы те же самые, что в `m`, а там мы уже и так проверяем дубликаты?

Comment: Так у нас для этого массив `b`, по условию.

Answer (score 2):

Замечание по коду: при такой организации матрицы можно работать с ней как с линейным массивом. Но для приличия и для наглядности вывода введём кол-ва столбцов и строк (`mw`, `mh`). Да, все величины здесь - однобайтовые, счётчики частоты тоже. Вывод на тестовой матрице будет такой:

```
   1   2   9   4
   5  14   7   8
   9  10  14  14
Duplicates(frq):
   9(2)  14(3)
```

Ну и само действие. Больше кода уходит на вывод, чем на суть :)

```
; ----------------------------------
section .data
matrix      db  1, 2,  9, 4
            db  5, 14, 7, 8
            db  9, 10, 14,14
mh equ      3
mw equ      4

; здесь храним элементы-дубликаты
dups        times mw*mh db 0
; а здесь - их количество
; то есть для элемента dups[N] его частота будет в frq[N]
frq         times mw*mh db 0

format_u    db  '%4u', 0
format_dups db  '%4u (%u)', 0
crlf        db  0Ah, 0
s_dups      db  'Duplicates(frq):', 0Ah, 0
; ----------------------------------
section .text
extern printf
global main
; ----------------------------------
main:
    cld
    push ds
    pop es
    call print_matrix

    xor edx, edx
    mov ecx, mw*mh
    mov esi, matrix
    ; ищем дубликаты
    ; esi = адрес 'matrix'
    ; ecx = длина 'matrix'
    ; edx = текущее кол-во элементов в массиве 'dups'
loop4:
    lodsb
    push ecx
    mov edi, esi
    dec ecx
    jcxz next2
    repne scasb
    jne next2

    ; нашли дубль, теперь ищем его в 'dups',
    ; edx - текущий размер 'dups':
    mov ecx, edx
    jecxz next1

    mov edi, dups
    repne scasb
    jne next1

    ; нашли, увеличиваем счётчик:
    inc byte [frq+edi-dups-1]
    jmp next2
next1:
    ; не нашли, записываем его в 'b':
    mov [dups+edx], al
    mov byte [frq+edx], 2
    inc edx
next2:
    pop ecx
    loop loop4

    ; вот и всё!
    push s_dups
    call print_string

    ; дублей нет, нечего и выводить:
    mov ecx, edx
    jecxz last1

    xor esi, esi
loop5:
    push ecx
    xor eax, eax
    mov al, byte [frq+esi]
    push eax
    mov al, byte [dups+esi]
    push eax
    push format_dups
    call printf
    add esp, 12
    inc esi
    pop ecx
    loop loop5

last1:
    xor eax, eax
    ret
; ----------------------------------
print_matrix:
    mov ecx, mh
    mov esi, matrix
    xor eax, eax
p1:
    push ecx
    mov ecx, mw
p2:
    lodsb
    push eax
    call print_int
    loop p2
    push crlf
    call print_string
    pop ecx
    loop p1
    ret
; ----------------------------------
print_int:
    pushad
    push dword [esp+36]
    push format_u
    call printf
    pop eax
    pop eax
    popad
    ret 4
; ----------------------------------
print_string:
    pushad
    push dword [esp+36]
    call printf
    pop eax
    popad
    ret 4
; ----------------------------------
```

Comment: Что конкретно комментировать, кроме того, что уже есть? Про `%4u` и прочие форматы - см. описание фукнции `printf` из стандартной библиотеки языка C. Именно она и используется здесь для вывода.

Comment: *Зачем добавлять нули (Times)* - что значит "добавлять"? Конструкция вида `A  times N db 0` создаёт переменную `A` (массив), состоящую из `N` нулевых байт. Во всяком случае в моём ассемблере (NASM). Если у вас другой - смотрите как это сделать в нём (MASM, TASM - инструкция `DUP`, кажется)

Comment: "*И про crlf, ноль в прерывание??*" - какое прерывание? Нулевой байт - признак конца строки. Стало быть, строка `crlf` состоит из всего одного символа `0Ah` (перевод строки). Возможно, если у вас Windows, то нужно сделать её такой: `crlf db 0Ah, 0Dh, 0`

Comment: *не понятно '%4u(%u)* - ответ тот же, см. описание функции `printf`. Этот формат задаёт вывод двух целых беззнаковых чисел, одно из которых выравнивается по ширине на 4 позиции, второе (которое при выводе будет в скобках) выводится как есть.

Comment: "*для чего нужен каждый loop*" - да что уж, давайте я сразу за вас контрольную сдам?

Answer (score 0):

а обязательно матрица 3 на 4?
предлагаю пройтись по массиву первый раз и сформировать таблицу символов с частотой встречаемости буфер будет выглядеть так 
buf dd 255 dup (0)
при встрече символа умножаем его на 4 и увеличиваем двойное слово по этому адресу +1, получим на выходе частоты символов в файле или массиве

Comment: Так, конечно, проще. Но только в одном случае: когда матрица состоит из байтов. Поэтому я и показал проход, который подойдёт для dw, dd, и вообще чего угодно.